# Hive's hour() function returns 12 hour clock value

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

According to the documentation Hives standard function hour() should return a value between 0 and 24 but for some reason I always get a twelve hour clock value, between 0 and 12. I'm using a `MySQLDateTime` field as a `Timestamp` field in my Hive table. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Are they stored as 0-12? Or it's just a retrieve problem?

Comment: It's just a retrieve problem. When I just select them without the function I see them correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found it. I looked at the source code and apparently `UDFHour.java` does have two `evaluate()` functions. One that does accept a `Text` object as parameter and one that uses a `TimeStampWritable` object as parameter. Both work with a `Calendar` instance but for some reason the first function returns the value of `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` and the second one `Calendar.HOUR`.

I've looked in the Hives documentation but I couldn't find anything about that second function, but it's there. I'm using Hive 0.9.0.16, which came with Hortonworks' HDP.

**Edit:**
I've reported this a while back. A patch is now available: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3850.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what `hive` has done, you could format the date to be returned as 24 hour format.

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(mydate)  
from mytable
;
```

Or you may update all datetimes stamps if it makes sense.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: @Pieterjan I am checking online to find if anyone else has encountered the same issue. If found something relevant, will keep you posted :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I posted, what I think is the issue below.

Answer (score 1):

The function `hour()` returns a 24h formatted result if it works with string format. You may use

`hour(cast (column_name as string))`

Answer (score 0):

for lower version of hive,I got a workaround

```
    hour(from_unixtime(
unix_timestamp(
from_utc_timestamp(
from_unixtime(round(created_at/1000)),'Etc/GMT-8')
)))
```

Since I am using EMR, I can not choose to use the latest version of hive, so I got this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an example for what has already been told above

HOUR(cast (from_utc_timestamp(my_date_timestamp ,'GMT') as string)) -- returns 24 hr format

HOUR(      from_utc_timestamp(my_date_timestamp ,'GMT') ) --returns 12 hr format