# How to convert 12-hour timestamp to 24-hour timestamp in hive?

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp

hive timestamp am/pm to 24-hour timestamp

hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20-JUN-84 11.25.32.000000021 PM','dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aa'),'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.S') from test.dual;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive's hour() function returns 12 hour clock value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121112/hives-hour-function-returns-12-hour-clock-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20-JUN-84 11.25.32.000000021 PM','dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS aa'),'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS') from test.dual;